# What are these strange characters in HTML source?

Tags: html, text, encoding

My friend runs a website and had an e-mail from Google Safesearch informing him he was hosting a phishing page. Turns out his cPanel was bruteforced (weak password) and they uploaded some of the pages onto his server. He told me about it and I wanted to take a look at how sophisticated are.

In many of the files, certain words/portions of text are strange. They display perfectly in a webbrowser, but are jumbled inside the HTML. I was wondering if anyone can tell me what this is?

Examples:

```
<title>WÐµlÑÐ¾mÐµ tÐ¾ ÐµÐ’Ð°y: Sign in</title>
<span class="txtbox_title">Ð Ð°sswÐ¾rd</span>
<a class="three" href="#">FÐ¾rgÐ¾t yÐ¾ur
```

It's also worth noting that there is normal text throughout the page that displays perfectly also.

I assume this is to stop the detection of certain words in the page, but I'm not sure. Any information would be great.

Edit: Originally was tagged as PHP. I realised that it probably shouldn't be so removed it. Be nice, kids.

Edit edit: For clarity, it's a phishing page targetting eBay users.

The examples I posted in the original post are (in order):

```
eBay: Sign In
Your Password
Forgot your [password]
```

As such I don't believe it to be any sort of malware, but a method of encrypting text to fight detection in browsers such as Chrome (which I assume detect 'hot' words in their algorithm).

Comment: Update: I've ran this through all sorts of Text-To-(OtherFormat) services I've found online, with no luck. What's stumping me is that the characters display fine through the browser, but they're not the real alphabetical characters. I literally have no idea about how the creator generated these strings or what they even are. Surely if it was something to do with HTML page encoding all the text would have to be in this format, not just certain 'hot' words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They UTF-8 encoded Cyrillic letters and possibly other characters chosen for their visual similarity to common Latin letters. You are viewing the page in an editor that does not interpret data as UTF-8 but as in Latin 1 encoding.

For example, what you see as “Ð¾” is actually two bytes, 0xD0 0xBE. When interpreted as UTF-8 data (which is what browsers do here), they represent “о” U+043E CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O. It is identical with the common Latin letter “o” in visual appearance (in any font that contains both letters), but coded as a separate character due to belonging to a different writing system. To any program, they are quite distinct characters, unless the program has been separately coded to handle “confusables”.

Such confusion is often intentionally created for various reasons. You are probably right in assuming that here the purpose was “to stop the detection of certain words in the page”. When e.g. “Forgot” is written using Cyrillic o’s (Fоrgоt), normal Find operations will find it when searching for “Forgot”.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. How would they have generated the strings? By hand? I ask because if there's such a tool available online I'm interested in reversing the remaining strings and do some further testing on others.

Answer (score 1):

My **best** guess is that there it is a custom type of keylogger. The `WÐµlÑÐ¾mÐµ tÐ¾ ÐµÐ’Ð°y`would be parsed by the keylogger to output some data into a database that can be mined later for important information.

My **second** guess is that it is a means to scare or mess with the person whom owns the site.

My **third** guess is that the virus was coded by china or some other language and when the code was translated back into `utf-8` it resulted in some of the unused characters to output the strange content.

**EDIT**

---

My **fith** guess is the the phishing website was programmatic getting the source code content of the ebay site and parsing it into it's own html file. And ebay has its own countermeasures against such a type of attack by scrambling the letter in the source code.

With this there must be some type of javascript that undoes the effects of the original source code.

Comment: For clarity, it's a phishing page targetting eBay users. 

The examples I posted in the original post are (in order): eBay: Sign In, Your Password, Forgot your [password]. As such I don't believe it to be any sort of malware, but a method of encrypting text to fight detection in browsers such as Chrome (which I assume detect 'hot' words in their algorithm).

Comment: Neoaptt, I think your third case is what it is, and that the third case is a resultant side effect of case 1 or 2.

Comment: Please see the reply/updated original post. I agree with it being something along those lines, but I think it's been purposefully done to evade certain detections. I'm wracking my brain to figure out how, seems very clever.

Comment: Neoaptt: I have access to the full code of the phishing page. The content is static, and it makes no such calls. The text seems to have been made this way for a specific purpose when the page was created.